# Probability using percentage to work out the number of balls

Tags: probability

I'm completely stumped with this question

There are 2 golf balls and (x) cricket balls 
Paul pulls one ball out of the bag and records his results ,then puts the ball back. 
After repeating the process it is known that the probability of taking out a ball of the same type twice in a row is 52% 
Calculate the amount of cricket balls

Comment: If there are $x$ cricket balls then there are $x+2$ balls in total.  the probability of getting two golf balls in a row is $\left( \frac 2{x+2} \right)^2$, the probability of getting two cricket balls in a row is $\left( \frac x{x+2} \right)^2$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let indicate with x the number of cricket balls then the probability of taking out a ball of the same type twice in a row is the sum of

- the probability of taking out twice a cricket ball
- the probability of taking out twice a golf ball

that is

$$p=\left(\frac{x}{2+x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{2}{2+x}\right)^2=0.52$$